# Problems with join on sorted key column but linux says "not in expected order"

Tags: linux, join

File 1. Column1=old_id;  Column2=snp_info (50 000 integers, so too large to show, containts 0,1,2,5 -> i.e., 020112202010511)

```
80024979
80024987
80025141
80107980
80922131
81666414
81667586
87021127
87028460
2010112924
2010115513
2010186050
```

File 2. Column1=old_id;  Column2=new_id.

```
79931168 58155
79944336 58190
79969242 72833
80107980 58150
80922131 58109
2010112924 96821
2010115513 80604
2010186050 47254
2010198857 90190
2010229173 96927
2010229330 67548
```

I am trying to join on column 1 which was sorted using sort -k 1n file1 and the same for file2.  When joining (in linux) I get the following error:

```
join: file 2 is not in expected order
join: file 1 is not in expected order.
```

If I look at the join, this is where it gives the error:

...200000010000000000000000 58150
join: file 2 is not in expected order -> but continues with the next old_id (file1) and their column2 value ->
80922131 1100000020000...

...001000010 58109 -> and then it stops here, that is again with column2 of file1 and column 2 of file 2 (the new_id column I want to put in).

I looked at the values, it start giving errors and stop where in file2 column 1 the old_id goes from a value with 8 integers to values of 10 integers.  Notice that it is indeed sorted correctly.

How do I solve this?  What is the cause?  Pictures included.  Thank you in advance.

File 1, column1, (column2 not shown, but = 0101020222015... -> 50 000 integers per id)

[image]

File 2, column1=old_id, column2=new_id

[image]

Result1 where it continuous:

[image]

Result2 where it stops.

[image]

Any help will be immensely appreciated.  Kind regards, Michiel.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and give us actual examples from your files. We cannot work with images, we need to be able to test things. You can use the [formatting tools](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to format your examples as code (use the `{}` button). If you show us examples of your two input files (we need both columns otherwise it isn't the right file) and then the output you expect, we can help.

Comment: Oh, and we also need to know the command you are running.

Comment: `join` expects the join columns to be sorted *lexically* rather than numerically

Comment: ... see [Join command is not working as expected](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526542/join-command-is-not-working-as-expected) and [Join two files ordered numerically according to second column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697402/join-two-files-ordered-numerically-according-to-second-column)

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you so much.  Again I learn something new (sorting lexically).  Greatly appreciated.  How do I mark this as the correct answer?

Comment: @terdon Thank you for showing me.  I was struggling to put it in the correct format.

Comment: You're very welcome, Michael. If one of the two links steeldriver gave you answer the question, just tell me which one and we can close this as a duplicate which means that anyone falling on this question will be redirected to the others, effectively marking this as answered.

Comment: @terdon https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/526542/join-command-is-not-working-as-expected worked.

Comment: Perfect, thanks!